# SQL query percentage of occurrence

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Given the following situation:

```
X    Y    Type 
----------------  
1    5    A   
2    7    B   
1    5    A   
1    5    C  
3    6    D
```

I want to turn this into percentages of A,B,C,D found on locations (X,Y).

Currently I do

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT( X,  ':', Y ) , TYPE , COUNT( TYPE )   
FROM  mine   
WHERE 1   
GROUP BY X, Y, TYPE 
ORDER BY X, Y, TYPE
```

which gives a nice result but needs a second pass in a programming language to get what I want.

In the end I want my result to look like this:

```
Loc Type Percentage    
-------------------
1:5  A    66    
1:5  C    33    
2:7  B    100     
3:6  D    100
```

Comment: what you mean by `second pass` ?

Comment: what is your question ??

Comment: Ho do you get percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not elegant, but it works:

```
SELECT CONCAT(x, ':', y),
       t,
       COUNT(t)/(SELECT COUNT(t)
                   FROM m AS m2
                  WHERE m.x = m2.x
                    AND m.y = m2.y)
FROM  m
GROUP BY x, y, t 
ORDER BY x, y, t
```

You can see an example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6a1e/3).

Comment: that is great, I didn't need anything elegant since this won't be in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        SELECT CONCAT(x, ':', y) as Loc,Type,
        round( COUNT(Type)/(SELECT COUNT(Type)
                   FROM mine AS t2
                   WHERE mine.x = t2.x
                    AND mine.y = t2.y)* 100 ,1) as percentage
     FROM  mine
     GROUP BY x, y, Type 
     ORDER BY x, y, Type
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44211/4)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT( m.X,  ':', m.Y ) , m.TYPE , COUNT( 1 ) Count , 100 * COUNT(1)/t.total Percentage
FROM  mine m INNER JOIN
      (SELECT X,Y,COUNT(1) total from mine group by x,y) t  
      on m.X=t.X and m.Y=t.Y
GROUP BY m.X, m.Y, m.TYPE, t.total
ORDER BY m.X, m.Y, m.TYPE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an identity column on the table you could do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mine (
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  x INTEGER,
  y INTEGER,
  type CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO mine (x,y,type) VALUES (1, 5, 'A');
INSERT INTO mine (x,y,type) VALUES (2, 7, 'B');
INSERT INTO mine (x,y,type) VALUES (1, 5, 'A');
INSERT INTO mine (x,y,type) VALUES (1, 5, 'C');
INSERT INTO mine (x,y,type) VALUES (3, 6, 'D');
```

.

```
SELECT CONCAT( m.X,  ':', m.Y ) 
 , m.TYPE 
 , COUNT(distinct m.id) TotalOfTypeOnXY
 , COUNT(distinct m2.id) TotalRecordsOnXY
 , 100 * (COUNT(distinct m.id) / COUNT(distinct m2.id)) Percentage
 FROM  mine m
inner join mine m2 
on  m.x = m2.x 
and m.y = m2.y
GROUP BY m.X, m2.x, m.Y, m2.y, m.TYPE 
ORDER BY m.X, m.Y, m.TYPE
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e94c